# Convert an arary of string encoded lists into a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I read a CSV file, my data is in `(1, 6000, 200)` shape but I want data in `(6000, 200, 6)` shape. Is there any possible way in Python to convert this string `[-9.3145  0.631   1.2924 -0.2776 -0.2061 -0.2084]` into the third dimension?

```
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
strain1 = glob("myfile.csv")
df = [pd.read_csv(f).values for f in strain1]
X_train = np.asarray(df)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you show a simple version of your CSV and the actual/expected result arrays?

Comment: BTW, calling a list a dataframe (`df`) is confusing

Comment: Welcome back to SO! Check out the [tour]. Please [edit] your question to add details. Of course there are ways to reshape data, but how exactly do you want to reshape it? It would help to provide a [mre] including some short example input, desired output, and actual output. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 1):

I used the below code to generate some test data:

```py
import numpy as np
test_data = np.array(["[{:0.4f} {:0.4f} {:0.4f} {:0.4f} {:0.4f} {:0.4f}]".format(*np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=10, size=(6,))) for k in range(100)]).reshape(1,20,5)
```

This hopefully produces something similar to what you have in your arrays. I have used the dimensions `20,5` where you had `6000,200` simply for convenience.

Numpy has a bunch of built in functions in the char module to help with this type of processing as can be seen [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.char.html).

```py
# Get rid of the (1,x,x) extra dimension 
data_squeezed = np.squeeze(test_data)
data_squeezed.shape
# Returns (20, 5)
# data_squeezed[0,0] = '[-0.3523 -8.3259 -1.2245 -4.8143 8.1495 7.3349]'

# strip the leading and trailing brackets []
data_stripped = np.char.strip(data_squeezed, '[]')
# data_stripped[0,0] = '-0.3523 -8.3259 -1.2245 -4.8143 8.1495 7.3349'

# split the string into parts
data_split = np.char.split(data_stripped, ' ')
# data_split[0,0] = ['-0.3523', '-8.3259', '-1.2245', '-4.8143', '8.1495', '7.3349']

# convert the array of lists to an array
data_array_of_strings = np.array(data_split.tolist())
# data_array_of_strings[0,0] = array(['-0.3523', '-8.3259', '-1.2245', '-4.8143', '8.1495', '7.3349'], dtype='<U7')

# convert the string values to float values
data_array = data_array_of_strings.astype(float)
# data_array[0,0] = array([-0.3523, -8.3259, -1.2245, -4.8143,  8.1495,  7.3349])

# Or as a one liner
data_array = np.array(np.char.split(np.char.strip(np.squeeze(test_data), '[]'),' ').tolist()).astype(float)

# Check the shape 
data_array.shape
# Returns (20,5,6) as required
```